# Null Reference exception on an array within struct array

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, nullreferenceexception

I receive a null reference exception at `Shapes[0].DamageofShape[0] = 7;`. Do I need to do another initialization somewhere?

```
   public struct TestArrayStruct
    {
        public int[] DamageofShape;
    }

class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestArrayStruct[] Shapes = new TestArrayStruct[5];

            Shapes[0].DamageofShape[0] = 7;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize `Shapes[0].DamageofShape`<sup>1</sup>, whose value is `null` by default:

```
Shapes[0].DamageofShape = new int[4];
```

You could do this in the constructor as well:

```
public struct TestArrayStruct
{
    public int[] DamageofShape;

    public TestArrayStruct(int size)
    {
        this.DamageofShape = new int[size];
    }
}
```

However, then you *would* have to instantiate your struct with the constructor to take advantage of it:

```
Shapes[0] = new TestArrayStruct(4);
Shapes[0].DamageofShape[0] = 7;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>a previous version if this answer said you had to instantiate `Shapes[0]`, which was incorrect

Comment: Thanks. I haven't written a structure for over a year, and that was in visual basic, so the context is slightly different.